# Fuzzy Finding in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In learning haskell, I'm writing a fuzzy menu. At the moment, my executable reads in a 'dictionary' from stdin, and ranks each word according to how well it fuzzily matches a search pattern given in the first CLI arg. The idea of the fuzzy matching algorithm is to split a pattern by its delimiters, and then match each character with a prefix of a token, accumulating a score to represent the quality of the match.

My main module looks like this:

```
module Main where

import           Data.List
import           Fuzzy
import           System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- getContents
  let dict = lines contents

  args <- getArgs
  let pattern = splitWord (head args)

  let scored  = map (\x -> (score (x, pattern), x)) dict
  print (sort scored)
```

I'm not sure whether or not I'm misusing the do block and/or some I/O primitives here: overall, I think it could be better but I don't know how to change it.

The Util module looks like this:

```
module Util
  ( splitWord
  , boolToFloat
  , nextChar
  ) where

splitWord :: String -> [String]
splitWord (l : '_' : r ) = splitWord ([l, '-'] ++ r)
splitWord (l : '.' : r ) = splitWord ([l, '-'] ++ r)
splitWord (l : ':' : r ) = splitWord ([l, '-'] ++ r)
splitWord (l : '-' : r ) = [[l]] ++ splitWord r

splitWord (c       : []) = [[c]]
splitWord []             = []

splitWord s              = do
  let rest  = splitWord (tail s)
  let first = (head s) : (head rest)
  return first ++ tail rest

boolToFloat :: Bool -> Float
boolToFloat True  = 1.0
boolToFloat False = 0.0

nextChar :: [String] -> [String]
nextChar s = case tail (head s) of
  [] -> tail s
  n  -> [n] ++ tail s
```

Especially in `splitWord`, I think the code here is somewhat repetitive, and again I don't really know how to make it simpler.

And finally, the Fuzzy module is as follows:

```
module Fuzzy
  ( score
  ) where

import           Util

score :: (String, [String]) -> Float
score ([], _ ) = 0
score (_ , []) = 0

score (s , t ) = boolToFloat (head s == head (head t))
  + max (score (tail s, t) * 0.8) (score (tail s, nextChar t))
```

This module (and function) is the one I have the least concerns about - most of the problems in my code (as I perceive them) are about IO and redundancy in splitWord's pattern matching. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think your use of do notation in the splitWord function is bad and I think your code is even correct by accident. Let me add parentheses to highlight it:

```hs
splitWord s              = do
  let rest  = splitWord (tail s)
  let first = (head s) : (head rest)
  (return first) ++ tail rest
```

Most people, including me, will assume the last return statement in a do block to be applied last, like this:

```hs
splitWord s              = do
  let rest  = splitWord (tail s)
  let first = (head s) : (head rest)
  return (first ++ tail rest)
```

Which is incorrect in this case! I would advise to just not use do notation here:

```hs
splitWord s              =
  let rest  = splitWord (tail s)
      first = (head s) : (head rest)
  in [first] ++ tail rest
```

2. Use pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail`:

```hs
  (arg:_) <- getArgs
  let pattern = splitWord arg
```

```hs
splitWord (l:r)              =
  let (l':r')  = splitWord r
      first = l : l'
  in [first] ++ r'
```

```hs
nextChar :: [String] -> [String]
nextChar ((_:[]):s) = s
nextChar ((_:n):s) = [n] ++ s
```

```hs
score ((hs:s, t@((hht:_):_)) = boolToFloat (hs == hht)
  + max (score (s, t) * 0.8) (score (s, nextChar t))
```

This also makes it more clear to me that your `score` function is partial: what should the result of `score ("x", [""])` be?

3. It is also in general more common to use curried functions instead of tuples as arguments:

```hs
score :: String -> [String] -> Float
score [] _ = 0
score _ [] = 0

score (hs:s) t@((hht:_):_) = boolToFloat (hs == hht)
  + max (score s t * 0.8) (score s (nextChar t))
```

4. You can make the `main` function a bit nicer with `fmap`:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  dict <- fmap lines getContents

  args <- fmap (splitWord . head) getArgs

  let scored  = map (\x -> (score (x, pattern), x)) dict
  print (sort scored)
```

But it looks decent without that too, so don't worry to much about that.

5. You can deal with the repetitiveness in `splitWord` by using guards and the `elem` function, change:

```hs
splitWord (l : '_' : r ) = splitWord ([l, '-'] ++ r)
splitWord (l : '.' : r ) = splitWord ([l, '-'] ++ r)
splitWord (l : ':' : r ) = splitWord ([l, '-'] ++ r)
splitWord (l : '-' : r ) = [[l]] ++ splitWord r
```

to:

```hs
splitWord (l : x : r )
  | x `elem` "_.:-" = [l] : splitWord r
```

Note that the `elem` function can be slower than pattern matching, so alternatively you can split out the pattern matching in its own function:

```hs
isSep :: Char -> Bool
isSep '_' = True
isSep '.' = True
isSep ':' = True
isSep '-' = True
isSep _ = False

...

splitWord (l : x : r )
  | isSep x = [l] : r
```

6. Use library functions like `break` in `splitWord`:

```hs
splitWord :: String -> [String]
splitWord s = case break isSep word of
  ([], x:r) -> x : splitWord r -- *
  (l, []) -> l
  (l, _:r) -> l : splitWord r
```

* This first case is a bit strange and maybe you don't need it, but I think it is needed to make this function match your splitWord function exactly.